# Exception when add user on Jboss 7

Tags: jboss

When i try to run the add user bat on jboss, so i can acces the console administration on jboss,
i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider __redirected.__SAXParserFactory could not be instantiated: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:204)
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:152)
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:232)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:127)
        at jdk.xml.internal.JdkXmlUtils.getSAXFactory(JdkXmlUtils.java:235)
        at jdk.xml.internal.JdkXmlUtils.<clinit>(JdkXmlUtils.java:78)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.<init>(SchemaParsingConfig.java:319)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.<init>(SchemaParsingConfig.java:254)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.<init>(XSDHandler.java:483)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.<init>(XSDHandler.java:490)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.<init>(XMLSchemaLoader.java:360)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.<init>(XMLSchemaLoader.java:295)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.<init>(XMLSchemaFactory.java:106)
        at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryFinder._newFactory(SchemaFactoryFinder.java:233)
        at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryFinder.newFactory(SchemaFactoryFinder.java:147)
        at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newInstance(SchemaFactory.java:213)
        at __redirected.__SchemaFactory.<clinit>(__SchemaFactory.java:66)
        at __redirected.__JAXPRedirected.initAll(__JAXPRedirected.java:88)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module$1.run(Module.java:85)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module$1.run(Module.java:72)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.<clinit>(Module.java:72)
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:255)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:192)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at __redirected.__RedirectedUtils.loadProvider(__RedirectedUtils.java:94)
        at __redirected.__RedirectedUtils.loadProvider(__RedirectedUtils.java:87)
        at __redirected.__SAXParserFactory.<init>(__SAXParserFactory.java:102)
        ... 27 more
```

Im using windows 10.

How can i solve this?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: My JAVA_HOME is pointing to java jdk 8